# g++ -O2 flag giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization, g++

The program below is a bst tree which works fine under unoptimized settings but produces a SIGSEGV under special circumstances. Since my debugging skills doesn't extend towards assembly, I can use some input to what is causing this error.  Below is the full code so it can be reproduced. There is nothing fancy, a node struct is there to hold node data, a simple insert operation and a method to confirm the height of the tree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

typedef struct avl_tree_node //node data
{
  int data;
  int balance{0};
  avl_tree_node *left{NULL};
  avl_tree_node *right{NULL};
  avl_tree_node *parent{NULL};

}node;

class avl
{
private:
  node *root;
  int get_height(node *head) //calculates the height
  {
    if (head == NULL)
      return -1;

    int l_height = get_height(head->left);
    int r_height = get_height(head->right);

    if (l_height > r_height)
      return l_height+1;

    return r_height+1;
  }

  void unbalanced_insert(node *head, int item); //method definition for a simple insert

public:
  avl(int data)
  {
    root->data = data;
    root->parent = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
  }

  int height() //gives the height
  {
    return get_height(root);
  }

  void unbalanced_insert(int item) //wrapper
  {
    unbalanced_insert(root, item);
  }

};

void avl::unbalanced_insert(node *head, int item) //inserts node to the tree
{
  //cout << "stepped" << endl;
  if (item > head->data)
    {
      if (head->right == NULL)
    {
      head->right = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      head->right->data = item;
      head->right->parent = head;
      head->right->left = NULL;
      head->right->right = NULL;
      head->balance = 1;
      return;
    }
      unbalanced_insert(head->right, item);
      head->balance++;
      return;
    }

  else
    {
      if (head->left == NULL)
    {
      head->left = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
      head->left->data = item;
      head->left->parent= head;
      head->left->left = NULL;
      head->left->right = NULL;
      head->balance = -1;
      return;
    }
      unbalanced_insert(head->left, item);
      head->balance--;
      return;
    }
}

int main()
{
  avl a(0);

  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) //works until i < 4
    {
      a.unbalanced_insert(i);
    }
  cout << a.height() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Under normal circumstances, I'd be happy that this works with unoptimized flags, but I have to build this with specific flags. One of such is the `-O2` flag. The segmentation fault occurs between the `avl a(0)` object construction and the for loop inside main. The error also seems to be dependent on the boolean check of the for loop. This works fine if `i < 4` and executed with: `g++ avl.cpp -g -O2 -o program && ./program`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious problem, and it occurs on the very first function call in `main`, i.e. `avl a(0)`:

`root->data = data;`

The `root` is uninitialized, thus the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I see my amateur mistake now. But why did it work under an unoptimized flag then?

Comment: Undefined behavior.  Anything can happen, including "work".

Comment: that explains it

Comment: @SilverFlash: If you want to know exactly why it happened to work with the bug, single-step the asm in a debugger and see what value `root->data` happened to be pointing to.

Comment: Technically, it didn't work. It just did something undefined, which happened to be what you expected ;).

Answer (score 0):

I guess when instantiate the object of avl here.

```
 avl a(0);
```

constructor of class as shown below is called.

```
avl(int data)
  {
    root->data = data;
    root->parent = NULL;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
  }
```

But here I see root pointer is not allocated any memory